# Group and preorder

Tags: group-theory, category-theory

Let $G$ be a group.
Let $a, b$ be elements of $G$.
We denote $\operatorname{Hom}(a, b) = \{ab^{-1}\}$.
Then we get a category whose set of objects is $G$.
We can regard this category as a preorder in the obvious way.
We denote this category by $P(G)$.
Let $G, H$ be groups.
Suppose $P(G)$ is isomorphic to $P(H)$.
Is $G$ isomorphic to $H$?

Comment: What obvious way is that?

Comment: @dfeuer From [a wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preorder):
[*Equivalently, a preordered set P can be defined as a category with objects the elements of P,
and each hom-set having at most one element (one for objects which are related, zero otherwise).*]

Comment: Isn't $P(G)$ isomorphic to $P(H)$ iff $|G|=|H|$?

Comment: @MakotoKato, the category you've defined induces the most boring preorder possible, which carries no information whatsoever.

Comment: @JackSchmidt Maybe. In that case, we need the proof. Regards,

Comment: @MakotoKato, you can write that yourself. It's trivial, once you've written out *exactly* what you mean by $P(G)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Proposition:** $P(G) \cong P(H)$ iff $|G|=|H|$.

*Proof:* If $P(G) \cong P(H)$ then there is a bijection between the sets of objects in  the two categories, that is, a bijection of $G$ and $H$. Hence $|G|=|H|$. Conversely, given any bijection $f:G \to H$ we define a functor $F:P(G) \to P(H)$ by defining $F_1:\mathcal{Obj}(P(G)) \to \mathcal{Obj}(P(H)): g \mapsto f(g)$ and $F_2:\operatorname{Hom}(g_1,g_2) \to \operatorname{Hom}(f(g_1),f(g_2)) : g_1 g_2^{-1} \mapsto f(g_1) f(g_2)^{-1}$. $\square$

Note that if you object on the ground that $F_2(x)$ is not well-defined if $x \in G$, then you are really objecting to the definition of $\operatorname{Hom}(g_1,g_2)$ since a category requires that each morphism has a designated source and codomain, yet labeling them only by elements of $G$ clearly requires different morphisms to have the same label. A functor is defined on morphisms, not on their labels, so I don't see any problem.

Comment: Since the OP is looking at the preorder, you don't need any of that fancy functor stuff anyway—just a plain old relational isomorphism.

Comment: @dfeuer: yup. they are both complete digraphs. I was just trying to use the language in the OP.